# Web-based form-builder for users in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, serialization, dynamic

First time posting in Stack Overflow, hope I'm doing this right.

I'm writing an app with Ruby on Rails right now. Without disclosing too much, the premise is that we have organizations and normal users. Organizations have events, which require users to answer a questionnaire before participating.

I'm pretty sure about these models / relationships that I will be using (this isn't really that important/pertinent to my question i think, but just wanted to give background):

- organization (one to many) events
- event (one to one) quesitonnaire)
- questionnaire (one to many) users
- (specific) response (one to one) user

The part I have a question about is how to implement the questionnaire. I want to give the ability to Organizations to essentially write / build their own forms. I'd like to stay away from them using code if that's possible (ie any DSL and whatnot).

I suppose the easiest way to do this is to give them a set number of text-area responses, so that I can consistently store the data and don't have to hassle around with how to configure storing this data (for example, maybe each event can only have exactly 5 responses to be filled in by textfield response by the user).

My ideal would be for the organization to be able to dynamically generate the forms on their own - maybe one questionnaire will have 1 text input, followed by 3 multiple choices, and maybe 2 short answers at the end; another one may have 5 multiple choices, and 1 short answer; yet another questionnaire might only have 1 text input...you get the idea.

So I see two parts of this problem - the first is the user interface for the organization to create the questionnaire. i'm imagining this wouldn't be terribly hard - ask them how many of each response type (MC, short answer) they would like to put into the form, give them the ability to rearrange them, etc.

The second part of the problem (what I'm more concenred about) is how to store/access this data. I'm guessing there's no dynamic-attribute sort of deal in ruby - storing some field with an unspecified number of parts and whatnot. i suppose i could make them all individual models (ie a question_response model, with :question, :response_type, :response, etc), but I'm fairly certain that's probably inefficient.

My initial guess is probably to serialize the data / use json; I worked briefly with Drupal 6 and this seems to be the way they did it. I was wondering if anyone else had any experience / suggestions though? I'm pretty new to Ruby so I was wondering if there's a gem out there or something that would help with what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: For starters have a watch of http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 - it's almost exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the Surveyor gem

http://vimeo.com/7051279
*slightly old how-to video

https://github.com/breakpointer/surveyor

Surveyor does come with it's own DSL which is relatively easy to use (although can be abit restrictive at times). The data is saved as a set of question - answer values, so there is no actual specific model (beyond Surveys -> Questions (question_groups) -> Answers).

Originally I did look at having people submit their own Surveyor DSL specs - which would then be used to generate the actual survey via a Rake command.

I think if you need to build a dynamic model (and save the data) it is possible, although I am not not sure if you'll be able to get the Rake tasks to run to build the actual tables in a dynamic way due to permission restrictions.

Have a look at http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/ and Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like the Ruby Pros by Paolo Perrotta, for some starters.